# Separate MX records for subdoma

Tags: email, gmail, google-apps, mx-record

I have a scenario where we have a member based subscription website that emails out alerts / updates like a forum but I also want to have the domain pointed to my own mailserver so I can create mailboxes for staff @domain / support @domain etc.

The problem is that due to the volume of mail traffic the site will be sending as it alerts / sends mail to users, it is better if I have the mail sent from the server it's hosted on or preferably Google Mail SMTP.

What I want to achieve is:

```
domain.com = MX records for my mailserver
mx.domain.com = MX records for Google Mail
```

The problem is I can't get it to work, I signed up to Google Apps with admin@mx.domain.com and it will not verify even after adding an meta tag in index.html in the subdomain.

[image: mx settings screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register the "mx" domain as an A record first.  You will have to "verify" your domain with Google via a TXT record or some other mechanism.  I suspect your lack of A record for the subdomain is the issue.